# How to use external angular modules in own Grafana plugin

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I’m developing my datasource plugin based on [simple-json](https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource). I want to use the library [angular-ivh-treeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview), but I do not understand how to use it in the plugin. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

To use an external JavaScript lib in a plugin, you have to include it in the plugin code. JavaScript libraries in node_modules are only used at build time and are not included in the output.

To take an example, here is the Plotly panel plugin that includes the Plotly lib in a subdirectory named `lib`:

https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-plotly-panel/tree/master/src/lib

and then uses it here:

https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-plotly-panel/blob/master/src/module.js#L8

Another example - the GeoLoop plugin that includes the mapboxgl library:

https://github.com/CitiLogics/citilogics-geoloop-panel/blob/master/src/geoloop.js#L3

Comment: I understand it. Thanks, but it not working. Grafana does not see directives of this library. I used another lib (jsTree).